# PyCharm не видит атрибут AF_UNIX библиотеки socket

Tags: python, сокет, отладка, pycharm

При построении маленькой программы с использованием библиотеки socket (Python 3.9) столкнулся с проблемой: PyCharm 2020.3 не видит атрибут AF_UNIX обозначенной библиотеки. Собственно, код:

```
import os
import socket
unix_socket_name = 'unix.sock'
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
if os.path.exists(unix_socket_name):
    os.remove(unix_socket_name)
sock.bind(unix_socket_name)
while True:
    try:
        result = sock.recv(1024)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sock.close()
        break
    else:
        print('Message:', result.decode('utf-8'))
```

Дебаг (build 203.6682.179) выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1477, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/panse/PycharmProjects/socket/socket_UNIX_server.py", line 5, in <module>
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'
```

Однако, в всплывающем вспомогательном окне он присутствует:
[image: скрин скрипта]

И также я его нашел в скрипте стокового модуля:

```
def socketpair(family=None, type=SOCK_STREAM, proto=0):
        """socketpair([family[, type[, proto]]]) -> (socket object, socket object)

        Create a pair of socket objects from the sockets returned by the platform
        socketpair() function.
        The arguments are the same as for socket() except the default family is
        AF_UNIX if defined on the platform; otherwise, the default is AF_INET.
        """
        if family is None:
            try:
                family = AF_UNIX
            except NameError:
                family = AF_INET
        a, b = _socket.socketpair(family, type, proto)
        a = socket(family, type, proto, a.detach())
        b = socket(family, type, proto, b.detach())
        return a, b
```

"Вошь ли я? Тварь ли я дрожащая?" или проблема в PyCharm? Заранее спасибо
P.S. В Sublime Text 3 такая же история

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как ясно из описания, [`socket.AF_UNIX`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.AF_UNIX) объявлен только если он поддерживается. На windows (судя по путям в ошибках, это тот случай, что в вопросе) это семейство пока не поддерживается.

За состоянием дел можно следить [в баге](https://bugs.python.org/issue33408). Если кратко, ничего сложного нет, есть мелкие проблемы с тестами, но на данный момент этим ни кто не занимается.

Comment: У меня была такая мысль после прочтения в socket.py, однако подумал, что ошибка во мне. Я взял этот код из обучающего курса 2019 года, у автора всё работало. Видимо что-то поломалось за два года. Благодарю за ответ